# Creating session number based on 'to' and 'from' character values

Tags: r, tidyverse, character, sequence

This seems silly but giving me trouble.
I have a data frame with multiple columns, one of them is experiment events (which are character strings), for example

```
Start
resp
lick
End
test
test
Start
lick
resp
lick
End
```

I want to add a column representing a session number that should start with the character "Start", and end with the character "End". These values should be consecutive, so the output would be

```
    Start 1
    resp  1
    lick  1
    End   1   
    test  0
    test  0
    Start 2
    lick  2
    resp  2
    lick  2
    End   2
```

Any easy ways to do this? I am sure tidyverse can do it, I am just not seeing it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting question, and harder than I thought. One way to do it is to first get the position of the rows that are between `"Start"` and `"End"` (using `sequence` and which), and then assign an ID to those rows, one for every sequence. This can be done in the following way:

```r
start <- which(dat$col1 == "Start")
end   <- which(dat$col1 == "End")
(s <- sequence(end - start + 1, start))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 10 11 

dat[s,"col2"] <- cumsum(c(1, diff(s) != 1))
dat[is.na(dat$col2),"col2"] <- 0
```

output

```
dat
    col1 col2
1  Start    1
2   resp    1
3   lick    1
4    End    1
5   test    0
6   test    0
7  Start    2
8   lick    2
9   resp    2
10  lick    2
11   End    2
```

data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Start = c("resp", "lick", "End", "test", "test", 
"Start", "lick", "resp", "lick", "End")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```